# MYSQL Insert Huge SQL Files of GB in Size

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, wikipedia, database-performance

I'm trying to create a Wikipedia DB copy (Around 50GB), but having problems with the largest SQL files.

I've split the files of size in  GB using linux split utility into chunks of 300 MB. e.g.

```
split -d -l 50 ../enwiki-20070908-page page.input.
```

On average 300MB files take 3 hours at my server. **I've ubuntu 12.04 server OS and Mysql 5.5 Server.**

I'm trying like following:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword database < category.sql
```

**Note: these files consist of Insert statements and these are not CSV files.**

Wikipedia offers database dumps for download, so everybody can create a copy of Wikipedia.
You can find example files here: [Wikipedia Dumps](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20091103/)

I think the import is slow because of the settings for my MySQL Server, but I don't know what I should change. I'm using the standard Ubuntu MySQL config on a machine with a decent processor and 2GB RAM. Could someone help me out with a suitable configuration for my system?

I've tried to set  innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1GB but no vains.

Comment: Why are you importing category.sql? It contains almost no useful information.

Comment: I am wondering how you would split 50G SQL inserts file into multiple 300G inserts by honoring SQL insert syntax. may be I am missing something...

Comment: @Aijazs :: Using Split i'm converting the files intp 300 MB chunks. Actually all the dumps are made in such format that each insertion statemnt is seprated by '/r' (Enter) delimeter. So i'm splitting up on the basis of line number.

Comment: @svick :: I've mentioned category.sql as example , my most concern is with page, text, revison and categorylinks . etc. tables.

Would you please suggest some good work around or suggestion so that i'm able to continue my work at higher pace ?

Comment: INtially the issues resolved by these settings, but now again i'm stuck . Any help @svick ??
Seed etails here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004117/mysql-huge-sql-files-insertion-myisam-speed-suddenly-slow-down-for-insertions?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have less than 50GB of memory (so you can't buffer the entire database in memory), the bottleneck is the write speed of your disk subsystem.

Tricks to speed up imports:

- MyISAM is not transactional, so much faster in single threaded inserts. Try to load into MyISAM, then `ALTER` the table to `INNODB`

  - Use `ALTER TABLE .. DISABLE KEYS` to avoid index updates line by line (MyISAM only)
  - Set `bulk_insert_buffer_size` above your insert size (MyISAM only)
  - Set `unique_checks = 0` so that unique constrains are not checked.

For more, see [*Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables* in MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).

**Note**: If the original table have foreign key constraints, using MyISAM as an intermediate format is a bad idea.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS` is the thing that is likely to help most. Don't forget to `ENABLE KEYS` afterwards :)

Comment: [The `category` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Category_table) doesn't have any foreign keys. But the related [`categorylinks` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Categorylinks_table) does have a foreign key to the `pages` table.

Comment: Well, thanks your solution works, It dramatically speed up the process. Now it take only 5-10 minutes that was previously around 2-3 hour. I'm amazed :)

Comment: INtially the issues resolved by these settings, but now again i'm stuck . Any help @svick  ??
Seed etails here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004117/mysql-huge-sql-files-insertion-myisam-speed-suddenly-slow-down-for-insertions?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Use MyISAM, usually much faster than InnoDB, if your data base isnt transaction oriented. Did you research into using any table partitioning/sharding techniques?

Converting huge MyISAM into InnoDB will again run into performance issues, so I am not sure I would do that. But disabling and re-enabling keys could be of help...